# API Delete not updating DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

So I have this request in my API which is called by a fetch request run on a button press:

```
router.delete('/itemDelete/:id', function(req, res, next){
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(user){
    var userTemp = user;
    var items = user.items;
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<items.length; i++){
      if(items._id == req.body.itemID){
        items.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
    userTemp.items = items;
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, userTemp, function(err, user){
      res.send(user);
    });
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

The code runs and there is no errors but the database does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this block is not error. There is no error checking, whether err is null or not. cmiiw

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, userTemp, function(err, user){ console.log("error:",err);res.send(user); };
```

Comment: Yeah it's null but there is a user with the ID passed which is weird.

Comment: May not enter condition inside if. 
items._id is ObjectID, right? you can use method .equals , or parse first with toString()

Answer (score 0):

To delete you can do so. But if to change status only you need to do update yourself.. Post the parameters you are passing

```
    User.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id }, function(err){...})
```

Comment: That will remove the entire user wont it? I only want to remove an item stored in the user model.